# Pandas prints out each dataframe cell's corresponding indexes

Tags: python, dataframe

I've been given an assignment to do, it is to convert a dataframe in this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLZh.png)

```
  Unnamed: 0 category 1 category 1.1 category 1.2 category 1.3
0        NaN    level1        level1       level2       level3
1   store id      Shelf      Pallets       Tables        Shelf
2       8445          3          NaN            4           12
3       8448        NaN            6          NaN           12
```

into this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZeJo.png)

```
   store id   category   level     type  number
0      8445  category1  level1    Shelf       3
1      8448  category1  level1  Pallets       6
2      8445  category1  level2   Tables       4
3      8448  category1  level3    Shelf      12
4      8445  category1  level3    Shelf      12
```

basically iterate through each cell in the dataframe and return its corresponding first column which is store_id and first 3 rows which contain the hierarchy.

I tried loops on the iloc or loc but kind of got confused, and didn't see too many posts that have a similar issue as mine,

Thanks for anyone who's willing to help!

Comment: Could you please post text/code, not images? That would make it much more easy for everyone trying to give an answer...

Comment: Will do, first time asking a question on here, thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

The fix that I use for the problem you are describing in your question:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value=(index,row["Column Name"])[1]
```

When you iterate through a dataframe, at least using iterrows(), it returns a tuple. Use the [1] outside the parentheses to select the second item in the tuple.

Note: Iterating through a dataframe is slow, and there is almost always a way around it. However, if you only have a few rows, and don't expect it to grow much, have at it. I find it is more intuitive than the various pandas commands.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Tyler for the answer, I read a few posts about the runtime issue with iterrows(), what would be the more efficient way around it?

Comment: TBH, I have only ever had use cases that are sub 1000 rows, so I just use iterrows to do my cleaning and drop it back in a df if I need to. I know that pandas has all the same abilities as SQL, so if you know SQL, you can just find the translations into pandas, but I have never used them.

Comment: In your case, you may want to use df.melt() to unpivot your dataframe. That seems to be what your use case requires.